# sql statement error, cant get random date

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

after i added newID for my sql code, my date cannot be display, anyway can correct my newID()? first of all newid() is for to get randam data from DB

**i get the answer that i want already and i will post it in next 8hours=)**

**work well**

```
enter code here
Select [Question],[r1] as [option],[Answer] From ExerciseTable where Question='" + 
((Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label3")).Text + "' AND [r1]!='null'
UNION 
Select [Question],[r2] as [option],[Answer] From ExerciseTable where Question='" +  
((Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label3")).Text + "' AND [r2]!='null' 
UNION 
Select [Question],[r3] as [option],[Answer] From ExerciseTable where Question='" + 
((Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label3")).Text + "' AND [r3]!='null'
```

**after i add newID() it no work**

```
Select [Question],[r1] as [option],[Answer] From ExerciseTable where Question='" + 
((Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label3")).Text + "' AND [r1]!='null' order by newID() 
UNION 
Select [Question],[r2] as [option],[Answer] From ExerciseTable where Question='" +
((Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label3")).Text + "' AND [r2]!='null' order by newID()
UNION 
Select [Question],[r3] as [option],[Answer] From ExerciseTable where Question='" + 
((Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label3")).Text + "' AND [r3]!='null' order by newID()
```

Comment: Firstly formatting is really bad, secondly SQL INJECTION and thirdly only the last part of the union needs the order by clause.

Comment: @V4Vendetta newID is to random to get sql data

Comment: @astander i added newID in my last union, it didnt work as well

Comment: NEWID() generates a new GUID value. You cannot order by a value. You order by column references.

Comment: If the error message you are receiving is "Msg 104, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator." then what it implies is that you need to include the ORDER BY column in the select list statement. Something like **SELECT col1, col2, NEWID() OrderCol FROM Tab1 UNION SELECT col1,col2, NEWID() OrderCol FROM Tab2 ORDER BY OrderCol**

Comment: anyway i get the correct answer that i want already=),thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the latest answer that does what I want.

```
Select * from (Select [Question],[r1] as [option],[Answer]
From ExerciseTable where Question='" + ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label3")).Text + "' AND [r1]!='null' 
UNION 
Select [Question],[r2] as [option],[Answer]
From ExerciseTable where Question='" + ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label3")).Text + "' AND [r2]!='null' 
UNION 
Select [Question],[r3] as [option],[Answer]
From ExerciseTable where Question='" + ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label3")).Text + "' AND [r3]!='null')t order by Newid()
```